# How can I get the list of affected rows (objects) when sending an update query with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I wish to update multiple items/rows/objects with an `update` query. But this query does not seem to return any objects after executing it. How can I get back the list with affected objects. For example with a query like this:

```
session.query(my_model).filter(
    my_model.status == 'OK',
    my_model.is_validated == True,
    my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now(),
).update({'status':'EXPIRED'})
```

I wish to get back the list with the updated objects. If I just add `all()` at the end for the query it does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this might be an incidental way to get a response back from the `update` method but you can get back information for the updated columns by using a `synchronize_session='fetch'` in the update method.

So the original query would be like:

```
session.query(my_model).filter(
    my_model.status == 'OK',
    my_model.is_validated == True,
    my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now(),
).update({'status':'EXPIRED'}, synchronize_session="fetch")
```

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#update-and-delete-with-arbitrary-where-clause).

Answer (score 1):

do you try this?:

```
 qry = session.query(my_model).filter(
       my_model.status == 'OK',
       my_model.is_validated == True,
       my_model.expires_at <= plum_dt.now(),
   )
 
 elements_to_update = qry.all()
 
 qry.update({'status':'EXPIRED'})
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the reply. I did and you get back the query result but that is not exactly the same as getting back the rows affected by the update query. I mean something could go wrong or a row could be deleted between the two queries or who knows what could fail and the update part could not work. With this solution  you would think that you updated everything but this might not be the case.

Comment: You can wrap your query in transaction if you are feeling that this could create issue.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi when you say put the query in a transaction you mean in a session ? like `with Session(engine) as session: query_1; query_2` How does that ensure that the update query was executed on the data returned from the select query? Isnt the select query executed first?

Comment: By the mean of transaction I mean to say that you can wrap your code in one commit, and if you found error then you can do conn.rollback so first open connection then create cursor and then execute these two queries in try except with that cursor at the end of try block execute conn.commit() and if exception found then do conn.rollback() this will ensure what you want.